# Unknown variable in class in Java

Tags: java, class, variables

I think it's stupid but I must know what that thing is (in the red circle), is it a variable or something? This is tutorial from YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF5m4o_CuNg).

I want to learn some about this but when I don't even know name of that I can't search info about this.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. 1) those are called class members. 2) please next time post code as text, not as a picture. 3) I suggest you take a look at a [better tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) (at least for the language part).

Comment: The code does not follow the [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 0):

Those are 3 variables.

- "private" is the access modifier,
- "EditText" is a variable type
- "Password" is name of the variable

Answer (score 0):

That are variables of specific types which are available in android. They store information about objects which are defined in some xml files. Usually their purpose is to add some logic to some graphic objects like text field or button.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Those are called attributes

Java is an object-oriented programming language. It means that we can create classes, with attributes (variables) and methods (functions), to represent (*abstract* may be a better word) concepts of the real world.

Let's say we want to represent a person in our program. We need to store the person's name and their e-mail address.

We can create a class `Person` with 2 **attributes**: `name` and `email`.

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String email;

}
```

Now we can create an *instance* of a `Person`, and fill the attributes with values:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String email;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Alice";
        person1.email = "alice@gmail.com";
    }

}
```

Let's say that we want to find out the e-mail provider of a `Person`. We can do that by creating a **method**.

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String email;

    public String getEmailProvider() {
        String emailProvider = email.split("@")[1];
        return emailProvider;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Alice";
        person1.email = "alice@gmail.com";

        String person1EmailProvider = person1.getEmailProvider();

        System.out.println(person1EmailProvider);
        // This prints: gmail.com
    }

}
```

The cool part about object-orienting is that you can create multiple *instances* of a `Person`, and fill their **attributes** with different values. So if you need to represent a, say, Bob, you can just `Person person2 = new Person()` and then set the **attributes** to the values that you want.

This is a **very** basic explanation of object-oriented programming. The internet has plenty of information about it, and I deeply recommend you to study this if you're a beginner.